# Order by user and then select max date

Tags: c#, oracle, linq, linq-to-sql

I have this LINQ query:

```
ArrayList arr = new ArrayList();
var data = conn.SCOT_DADOS.OrderByDescending(x => x.DATE)
                          .GroupBy(r => r.USER)
                          .ToList();
foreach (var item in data)
{
    var itemdata = item.Where(r => r.DATE == item.Max(s => s.DATE));

    var name = svc.GetUserName(itemdata.Select(r => r.USER).First().ToString());
    var value = itemdata.Select(r => r.VALUE).First();
    var date = itemdata.Select(r => r.DATE).First().ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");

    arr.Add( new{ NAME = name, DATE = date, VALUE = value} );
}
```

This code will give me the latest result by `DATE` for each `USER`.

But the LINQ query is selecting all data from the user and then I'm getting the latest one in the foreach loop.

Is there any way to get only the last data in the LINQ query, so I don't have to take all the user data every time?

---

I have tried this:

```
var data = conn.SCOT_DADOS.OrderByDescending(x => x.DATE)
                          .GroupBy(r => r.USER)
                          .First()
                          .ToList();
```

And then treated `item` as an object, instead of running selects on it.

It gave me all the data for an individual user, which isn't what I want.

What can be done?

---

Edit 1:

I get this error if I try to swap `OrderByDescending` and `GroupBy`:

> Error CS1061  'IGrouping' does not contain a
>   definition for 'DATE' and no extension method 'DATE' accepting a first
>   argument of type 'IGrouping' could be found (are
>   you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

---

Edit 2:

This is some sample data (the column names are not the same because I translated them for the question):

[image]

From the data presented, I'd have the results:

[image]

Comment: Try swapping the Order and Group.

Comment: I get an error on that. I'll add to the question.

Comment: @Phiter Fernandes - Please explain what you mean. Adding example input and result data will help

Comment: Is User a class or simply a property. If you want to order an already ordered list use: myList.OrderBy(o => o.MyProperty).ThenBy(o => o.OtherProperty)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the combination of the (USER, DATE) pair is unique (which seems to be the case when looking at the sample data), the requirement can be trimmed down to

> return each record if there is no other record with the same USER and later DATE

which could be translated to the following LINQ query:

```
var result = conn.SCOT_DADOS
    .Where(r => !conn.SCOT_DADOS.Any(r2 => r2.USER == r.USER && r2.Date > r.Date))
    // end of Db Query 
    .AsEnumerable()
    .Select(r => new
    {
        Name = svc.GetUserName(r.User),
        Value = r.Value,
        Date = r.Date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss")
    }).ToList();
```

Comment: I could do this using the primary key as well. The latest date will also be the latest ID. Would it be safer?

Comment: Well, if you can rely on it (I guess it's auto number). I would rather include it as a safety check  -  like `r2  => r2.USER == r.USER && (r2.Date > r.Date || (r2.Date == r.Date && r2.Id > r.Id))`

Comment: It's returning nothing

Comment: Well, I've tried it before posting on a similar table in my EF test environment and it was returning data. Honestly I have no idea why it doesn't work for you.

Comment: My bad, I was looking at the wrong variable. This did work!  Just to bother you a little bit more. How can I order the results by value, descending?

Comment: After `Where(...)`, insert `.OrderByDescending(r => r.Value)`

Answer (score 2):

I'm a bit confused but from your attempts with `First()` think you mean this:

```
conn.SCOT_DADOS.GroupBy(item => item.User)
               .Select(grp => grp.OrderByDescending(i => t.Date).First());
```

This will retrieve **for each** `User` **only the latest record** of it

---

The reason only swapping the `GroupBy` and `OrderByDescending` isn't enough and that you need the `Select` is that once you grouped that data your enumerable is `IEnumerable<IGrouping<User,YourType>>`. Each `IGrouping` is actually a collection by itself so you need to `Select` only the 1 item you want from it.

Another way is to replace the `Select` with:

```
.SelectMany(grp => grp.OrderByDescending(i => t.Date).Take(1))
```

IMO the first is cleaner, but the second is in the case you need for each user N first items

---

On the query above you can also add what you have in the `foreach` loop:

```
conn.SCOT_DADOS.GroupBy(item => item.User)
           .Select(grp => grp.OrderByDescending(i => t.Date).First())
           .AsEnumerable()
           .Select(item => new {
               Name = svc.GetUserName(item.User),
               Value = item.Value,
               Date = item.Date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss")
           }).ToList();
```

*The use of the `AsEnumerable()` is to invoke the query to be executed to the database before the last `Select()` which uses the `GetUserName` method that will not be known to the Oracle database*

*IMO representing the `DateTime` as string is not a good way..*

---

**Update** - The error you get:

> Oracle 11.2.0.3.0 does not support apply

It seems that as for this version of Oracle it does not support `GroupBy` with `Select` via linq. See [Linq to Entities Group By (OUTER APPLY) “oracle 11.2.0.3.0 does not support apply”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29705013/linq-to-entities-group-by-outer-apply-oracle-11-2-0-3-0-does-not-support-appl).
One answer there recommended to create a view in the database for this and then use linq to select over that view. That is what I'd go for

Comment: I'm trying your solution now. I'm representing DateTime as string because it's going to be shown to the user.

Comment: It gave me *The method 'First' can only be used as a final query operation. Consider using the method 'FirstOrDefault' in this instance instead.*

Comment: Also, I had to change to  `OrderByDescending(i => i.Date)`

Comment: @PhiterFernandes - Is it ReSharper that says that?... I usually do prefer to use `FirstOrDefault` to avoid exceptions in the case of an empty collection - but because this is the result of a `GroupBy` each inner collection has at least 1 item in it - so first will be fine too

Comment: No I don't have ReSharper. It's an execution error.

Comment: After fixing it, I came upon another problem. **Oracle 11.2.0.3.0 doesn't support APPLY**   I forgot to mention that the DB is oracle, and it's outdated.

Comment: @PhiterFernandes - Are you using the query with the second `Select` too?

Comment: I'll use it now. Should I assign the results to `arr`?

Comment: @PhiterFernandes - the result will be of type of `List<T>` - I think better change `arr` to that type instead of `ArrayList`

Comment: Seems like I can't use my function inside the expression:    Additional information: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String GetUserName(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Comment: I made your changes but I still get the oracle error. It **doesn't support APPLY**

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
conn.SCOT_DADOS.GroupBy(x => x.User).Select(x => new
                {
                    User = x.Key,
                    Date = list.Where(y => y.User == x.Key).Max(y => y.Date)
                });
```